# libsvm: scaling data results in less features?

Tags: svm, scales, libsvm

I've scaled my training and testing data in BASH like so:

```
SCALE=$DIR/svm-scale
TRAIN=$DIR/svm-train
TEST=$DIR/svm-predict
#KERNEL='-t 0' #Uncomment line to do linear kernel
REGULAR='-c'

$SCALE -l -1 -u 1 -s coefs.txt train.txt > train_scaled.txt
$SCALE -r coefs.txt test.txt > test_scaled.txt
```

In my original train.txt and test.txt I had 161 features, but in my train_scaled.txt I only have 153 features, and some lines have less than that.

I may simply need to debug other parts of my code, but since I've been banging my head on this for so long, I thought I would ask if this is due to some unknown property of svm-scale.

Answer (score 1):

`svm-scale` doesn't reduce the number of features. An edge scenario that may cause this behaviour is when you have features with only a single value across all data instances.

Please post `coefs.txt` and any command line output you got, maybe we can diagnose the problem there.

Comment: Can you describe what this edge scenario is? I've it seems that my coefs.txt is missing certain features. How do I prevent this problem?